# Does Threefish-512 from BouncyCastle need some sort of configuration?

Tags: java, cryptography, hsqldb, bouncycastle

I'm trying to get a jdbc hsqldb instance encrypted using threefish-512 from bouncycastle. Hsqldb supports configuring this via the connection url: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_crypt_props. I'm familiar with the essentials of cryptography and such but have never worked with JCE, bouncycastle, etc.

I first added `crypt_type=Threefish-512;crypt_key=de7e...` to my connection string. This threw exceptions about unknown providers and algorithms. Specifying `crypt_provider=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` did not fix this.

I then added `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` to my code before the jdbc initialization and now `crypt_type=Threefish-512;crypt_key=de7e...` (without crypt_provider) seems to work mostly. It throws a new exception though:

> Illegal key size or default parameters

My crypt_key is 128 hex chars, so it's a 512 bit key. I doubt the key is the problem here. Debugging the Cipher class shows the key is indeed parsed to an array of 64 bytes.

Do I need to do some sort of configuration on bouncycastle/threefish after adding it as a provider? Simple information about this subject seems to be pretty sparse around the internet, there's no quick start to bouncycastle's threefish or other mentions of this problem or anything that I could find.

---

Spring boot project, hsqldb 2.4.0, bouncycastle 1.59 from maven org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on. Everything already works (db connection and such), I'm just trying to add encryption of the db on top of it. Normally, all you need to do for that is adding the crypt_* parameters to the connection string and hsqldb will handle the rest.

`public static void main(String[] args) {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    ConfigurableApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);`

application.properties
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:${app.db.path};create=${spring.datasource.initialize};hsqldb.tx=mvlocks;hsqldb.tx_level=serializable;crypt_type=Threefish-512;crypt_key=de7e...`

Am I missing something like this?

`BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
provider.setParameter("foo", "bar");
Security.addProvider(provider);`

Comment: Can you show your full code please? That would be really helpful in order to find out what's going on.

Comment: That's really all the code there's to it. I've added BouncyCastleProvider to the security providers, set crypt_type and crypt_key on the jdbc string, and everything else is handled by hsqldb internally. Aside from that it's just a standard spring boot project with plain jdbc etc.

Comment: Could you at least show the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wrky9dSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh. Silly US lawmakers and their shenanigans. I was using java 8u151, which still has the restricted crypto policy. Updating to u161 solved the problem.